# Как подключить файл из другой подпапки

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как подключить таблицу стилей из другой папки ? 
Уже все перепробовал и так `import  "./сss/bootstrap.min.css";` и вот так `import  "../сss/bootstrap.min.css";` и даже так `import  "src/сss/bootstrap.min.css";` и всё время получаю ошибку о несуществующем модуле. Помогите разобраться, Директория папок на рисунке ниже[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Нужно попасть в папку css и подключить bootstrap.min.css.

Answer (score 0):

Можно реализовать следующим путем

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
```